# this.state.message null is not an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to put my response from my back-en on my view. But when i put my this.state.message i have an error 'null is not an object this.state.message'.

This is the part of my view

```
</View>
          <View style={{flex:1}}><Text style={{color:'white', textAlign:'center'}}>{this.state.message}</Text></View>
        </View>
```

And also my back-end

```
connexion: (req, res, next) => {
    const verifEmail = RegExp("([A-z]|[0-9])+@([A-z]|[0-9])+.[A-z]{2,3}");
    const email = req.body.email;

    if (
      verifEmail.test(email) == false ||
      typeof req.body.password != "string" /**check des formats emails et pwd */
    ) {
      res.status(417);
      res.json({
        message:
          "Saisie incorrects. Veuillez ressaisir vos identifiants et mot de passe.",
      });
    } else {
      /*comparaison email user et base de donnée si match ou pas */
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, data) => {
        if (!data) {
          return res
            .status(401)
            .json({ message: "Identifiant et/ou Mot de passe incorrects" });
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, data.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
              message: "une erreur s'est produite",
            }); /*erreur de saisie ou autre err*/
          } else if (!data || !result) {
            res.status(401).json({
              message:
                "Identifiant et/ou Mot de passe incorrects" /*donnée ne matche pas avec database*/,
            });
          } else {
            res.json({
              club: data.club,
              userId: data._id,
              token: jwt.sign({ userId: data._id }, "RANDOM_TOKEN_SECRET", {
                expiresIn: "24h",
                /*durée de validité du Token, l'utilisateur devra se reconnecter au bout de 24h*/
              }),
              message: "Connexion Réussie !" /*good password */,
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  },
```

I have the same for my subcription view and it's working. I don' t understand why it doesn't work for my login view.

Comment: how are you querying the backend/updating the state on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

use this sample code for get data from server first :

```
  fetch(url + 'ApiService/test', {
            method: 'Post',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   },
            body: JSON.stringify(res),
          }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              console.log("responseJson: "+responseJson);
              this.setstate({message: responseJson.message});

}
```

then first check `console.log("responseJson: "+responseJson);` for your receive data from server is correct .
then use   `this.setstate({message: responseJson.message});` for set data for your state . I hope that's helpfully .